# Replace content from file with specific conditions

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

i want to replace content from file with specific conditions. 
Example :

```
if we have to replace LA to SF .     
if we have lable (after LA characters ) - No replace
if we have LA (after that one space ) - replace
if we have LA. (after that one dot) -  replace
```

PHP Code :

```
<?php

    if(isset($_POST['search']) && isset($_POST['replace']))
    {

            $search = trim($_POST['search']);
            $replace = trim($_POST['replace']);
            $filename = 'lorem.txt';
            $text_content = file_get_contents($filename);
            $contents = str_replace($search,$replace,$text_content,$count);

            $modified_content = file_put_contents($filename,$contents);

    }
?>
```

HTML Code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

<form method="post" action="">
<input type="text" name="search" />
<input type="text" name="replace" />
<button type="submit"> Replace </button>

</body>
</html>

?>
```

I tried with preg_replace but i have two words one which is **search** and second one is **replace** so how to achieve this kind of functionality using preg_replace or any other functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [word boundaries](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) (`\b`) to make sure a phrase is not a sub part of another word. For example

```
\bla\b
```

will find `la`, with the `i` modifier it will search case insensitive.

Regex Demo: https://regex101.com/r/bX9rD4/2

PHP Usage:

```
$strings='if we have lable 
if we have LA 
if we have LA.';
echo preg_replace('/\bla\b/i', 'SF', $strings);
```

PHP Demo: https://eval.in/613972

Comment: great it's working perfectly .. thank you so..much brother for the quick solution :)